# Referring to a JavaFx element with a String

Tags: java, javafx

Maybe a dumb question, but couldn't solve it and should be a quick one for someone how knows.

I have a JavaFx AnchorPane and I want to change its style. However, I'm getting the name of the Pane from somewhere else and saving it in a String. How can I do it?

```
public class Controller{
@FXML
    private AnchorPane PaneNumber1;

@FXML 
    private void changePaneStyle(ActionEvent actionEvent){
PaneNumber1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;"); 
}
//this works

String Name = PaneNumber1;

// now, how can I perform the same operation as above, using this String instead of PaneNumber1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely one way to do it is to have some kind of static Map that would map String to AnchorPane. That way when you get a name of the panel you could easily access it and do the operations as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `id` of your `Node`s is not overwritten, the `fx:id` is used. You could therefore use `lookup` to find the node, if you inject the root of the fxml to the controller:

```
@FXML
private Parent root;

@FXML
private void changePaneStyle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    root.lookup("#"+Name).setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;"); 
}
```

Alternatively you could use the `namespace` of a `FXMLLoader`, which contains the `Object`s by `fx:id` after loading the fxml, but you'd need to pass this data to the controller after loading:

```
private Map<String, Object> namespace;

public void setNamespace(Map<String, Object> namespace) {
    this.namespace = namespace;
}

@FXML
private void changePaneStyle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    ((Node) namespace.get(Name)).setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;"); 
}
```

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url);
Parent root = loader.load();
loader.<Controller>getController().setNamespace(loader.getNamespace());
```